# Перегрузка функций по имени параметра

Tags: c++, перегрузка-функций

Такой вопрос, (я только учусь, так что не бейте) есть функция, которая удаляет элемент из массива:

`void arrayEditingDel(int *&arr, int &size, int numdel){}`

Есть та, которая добавляет:

`void arrayEditingAdd(int *&arr, int &size, int newValue){}`

Почему бы не перегрузить одну функцию, вместо того, чтобы создавать две, верно?) Но мы ведь знаем, что перегружать функции можно либо по вз. типу, либо по кол-ву аргументов. И действительно, компилятор на попытку ругается:

`void arrayEditing(int *&arr, int &size, int numdel){}`

`void arrayEditing(int *&arr, int &size, int newValue){}`

В итоге, я своего добился, и перегрузку сделал:

`void arrayEditing(int *&arr, int &size, int numdel){}`

`void arrayEditing(int *&arr, int &size, int numdel, int newValue){}`

Но все это ценой бессмысленного действия (int numdel не используется при добавлении элемента в массив).

Вот собственно и вопрос: почему нельзя добавить возможность перегрузки по имени переменной? Компилятор спокойно, при вызове функции, сможет понять, какую реализацию ему задействовать. Или нет?

В общем, это несовершенство языка, или (скорее всего) моя некомпетентность?)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101684/discussion-on-question-by-sov-harlem-c--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузку по имени параметра функций сделать нельзя. Причин тому, как минимум три:

1. Имя параметра не является обязательным, т.е. вполне валидна функция, определённая как `void f(int)`. Для вызова требуется целочисленный параметр, но имени у него нет и достучаться до него переносимым способом нельзя.
2. Имя параметра может отличаться в объявлении (например, в .h-файле) и определении (например, .cpp-файле) функции.

   ```
   // заголовочный файл 
   void f(int a); 

   // файл реализации
   void f(int b) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
3. В месте вызова функции формальное имя параметра не используется. Например, объявление функции выглядит как `void f(int a);`, а вызов такой:

   ```
   int c = 42;  
   f(c);
   ```

   Или даже такой:

   ```
   f(42);
   ```

   Если бы была возможность существовать одновременно нескольким функциям, типа `void f(int a)` и `void f(int b)`, то было бы совершенно неясно, какую из них следует вызывать.

Более того, если вернуться к вашей идее, то давать одинаковые имена функциям, делающий радикально разные действия, не очень хорошая мысль. Намного удобнее, когда действие сразу отражено в названии функции (`Add`, `Del` из вашего вопроса). В таком случае, не нужно переходить к месту определения/объявления и читать код или описание того, что же действительно делает функция, принимающая такие-то параметры в таком-то порядке.

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить в ответ понятие сигнатуры метода, в уникальность которой, собственно, вопрос и упирается. А то на пальцах-то Вы объяснили, а само определение того, что объяснили, не ввели :)